# Stacking a time series

Tags: vba

```
1/2012 36.5
2/2012 37.1
3/2012 37.5
4/2012 37.9
5/2012 38.0 
6/2012 38.1
7/2012 38.3
```

I have a time series (dates as the first column and the values as the second). I am trying to select the first 5 values of the series from the top, copy and paste it into the second worksheet in the excel file, then go back to the first sheet, grab the next five values of the series, go to the next sheet and place the 5 values as the next column. So I am trying to stack the series by 5's side-by-side on the next sheet. How do I do that?

So far I have been trying to this process on the same page and this is where I am so far.

```
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(5, 0)).Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).PasteSpecial
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.End(xlToLeft).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(5, 0)).Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).PasteSpecial
```

Any help would be appreciated. Again I am trying to stack the series side-by-side by lengths of 5. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TT()

Const BLOCK_SIZE As Long = 5
Dim rng As Range, rngDest As Range

    Set rng = ActiveCell.Resize(BLOCK_SIZE, 1)
    Set rngDest = ActiveSheet.Parent.Sheets(2).Range("A1")

    Do While Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0
        rngDest.Resize(BLOCK_SIZE, 1).Value = rng.Value
        Set rng = rng.Offset(BLOCK_SIZE, 0)
        Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(0, 1)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! I'll definitely try it now.

Comment: Trying to run this code but it keeps giving me an error? What am I doing wrong?

    range("5D:10D").Copy
    range("G5").PasteSpecial  or Cell(5,7).PasteSpecial


In VBA do you specify an data array using the "Set" function and then have the ability to call that array in the code?

    Set datarng = range("A1:D7")

Comment: That's not the code I posted, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do there.  I assumed you were using pastespecial because you only wanted to transfer values: is that the case?